# I want to write a function that iterates through a list?

Tags: c++, list

I want to write a function that iterates through a list, but takes two elements if they equal a target.

The logic could be to have two loops; first iterate through list and see if any element + the first = target, then second, then third
etc..

```
int i;
int max = list.size;
for(i=0; i<=max; i++)
{
    if()
}
```

in c++

```
    int i;
int max = resistors.size();
int curr;
    for(curr = 0; curr<=resistors.size(); curr++)
    {
   for(i=1; i<=max; i++)
       {
        if((resistors[curr]+resistors[i])==target){
            ComposeSerial(resistors[curr], resistors[i]);

        }
       }
```

}

i believe one thing is missing to make sure that it goes through again?

Comment: If it's homework, add a tag for it.

Comment: Is that `std::list<int>`? Is it sorted?

Comment: the list is passed in, in this case im calling it list

Comment: You're going to have to do a lot of looping to get this algorithm to work. Start at index 0 and try adding every other element in the list to it to get the target, then move on to 1 and try adding every other element after it to get the target, then move on to index 2 and try adding every other element after it to get the target, etc.  Do you really need to do this? Can you state the original problem?

So, you'll have an outer loop, with another loop on the inside.

Comment: the original problem is that i have a list with many elements, i have to create a series with those two elements that equal a target

Comment: @user570098 : The fact that your variable is named `list` doesn't tell us **anything** about what type it is, so I don't see how you can get any reasonable answer. For that matter, I still don't understand what your question is.

Comment: You want to set i = curr at the beginning of the loop, but yeah that's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you thought about it slightly differently.  You said "first iterate through list and see if any element + the first = target".  What if you phrased it as "Iterate through the list and see if the current element + any other element in the list = target".  All I've done is consolidated your placement of "the first, then second, then third etc..." into the "current element".

Your original phrasing suggests only one loop, with some magic to get the first element, then the second, etc.  This reversed phrasing suggests two loops: one to get each element, then an inner loop to test the current element with every other element in the list.  Hopefully that way of thinking will clear up any confusion.

**Edit:**

Since this didn't clear up all the confusion, I'm going to add some pseudocode:

```
for all items in list
    for all items in list
        if element from outer loop and element from inner loop meet your condition
             return some value
```

One obvious optimization would be for the inner loop to start after the element from the outer loop, like so:

```
for all items in list
    for all items in list after the element from the outer loop
        ...
```

Depending on the problem, you may want to include the outer element at the start of the inner loop:

```
for all items in list
    for all items in list starting at the element from the outer loop
```

To write the actual code, grab your textbook, or the nearest C++ reference, or go to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com), look up the documentation for the specific container type you're using, and determine the best way to iterate through your elements from there.

**Edit 2 - Response to Edited Question**

Thanks for the updated question.  The only issues I see here are, as @leetNightshade pointed out in the comment, the inner loop should start at `curr + 1` (or `curr`, if you want to allow the test for an element with itself, which you probably don't), and your loops should terminate when `curr < resistors.size()`, and `i < max`, respectively.  Otherwise, you will include one element past the end of your list in your loop, which will have nasty consequences.

Comment: how do i go about doing this?

Comment: I added some more explanation to my answer.  Remember that SO does not exist to do your homework for you.  We also respond better when we see how much effort you have put into solving the problem.  If you are still having trouble, edit your original question with what you have so far, and we will be better able to help you.

Comment: @Daniel Gallagher Oh, should I not be attempting to post code then?

Comment: @leetNightshade: Different people have different thoughts about homework question.  Most people that I've seen here discourage solving problems directly, instead opting to post hints and point the poster in the right direction.  Also check out this [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework) (or [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)) on meta.

Comment: @Daniel Gallagher Also, he never said it was for homework, so how can you be certain it is? Is it his refusal to tell us that hinted you off?

Comment: @leetNightshade: I can't be certain, that's true.  And based on his updated post, I'm thinking that assumption is incorrect.  However, my comments on wanting to see what the poster has tried so far should still be perfectly valid.  His edit makes this question much, much better, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this question was a confusing/weird one, but I've got something that's still a work in progress for you.  It's a bit weird, but bear with me.

```
template<typename V>
V Add(const V v1, const V v2)
{
    return v1 + v2;
}

template<class T,typename V>
bool FindTwoEqualTarget(const T& list, const V target, V& elem1, V& elem2, V (*Process)(const V v1, const V v2) = Add)
{
    for(T::const_iterator iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); )
    {
        T::const_iterator iter2 = iter;
        iter = iter2++;
        for( ; iter2 != list.end(); ++iter2)
        {
            if(target == Process((*iter),(*iter2)))
            {
                elem1 = (*iter);
                elem2 = (*iter2);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
list<int> iList = list<int>();
iList.push_back(5);
iList.push_back(6);
iList.push_back(1);
iList.push_back(4);
iList.push_back(3);
iList.push_back(9);

int val1;
int val2;
FindTwoEqualTarget(iList, 11, val1, val2);
```

I know you want the function to return a list, I'm playing around with some things now to easily set this up for you, but you can work off of this for now I think.